# Cell element becomes False after reformatting a row, leading to an error

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm running into a bug after reformatting a row of a Tabulator table in my Vue app.

In my case, I have a column with dropdown cells (i.e. the Tabulator list editor). I want to format all dropdowns in my table a bit differently, so they can be easily distinguished by the user. For that purpose, I have created a generic `formatterDropdown` function that is used in definition of the dropdown columns. This formats the cells in my desired style (with an arrow) on re-rendering of the cell. This works fine, see here:

[Image of table with formatted dropdown cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryMun.png)

The issue arises when I select the already selected value of a dropdown, e.g. clicking the dropdown and selecting "Office", which was already the value of the cell. This first clears the cell, after which the cell should be re-rendered and formatted. However, as the value remains the same, re-rendering is not triggered and the cell remains empty... See this minimal code example of the `formatterDropdown` function at this point:

```
function formatterDropdown(cell, formatterParams, onRendered) {
  // Format cell when rendered
  onRendered(() => {
    const value = cell.getValue() || "";
    const element = cell.getElement();

    // Create elementDiv with some specific formatting...
    elementDiv = ...

    // Append to HTML element
    element.appendChild(elementDiv);
  });
}
```

I implemented a workaround that calls `row.reformat()` when the new value is equal to the old value. This works, but doesn't seem to be a very nice solution, so recommendations for improvement are welcome. Additionally, this solution does run into an error within the Tabulator source code. At that point my table is already properly rendered, so in that sense the workaround is fine, but the error remains present. See workaround here:

```
function formatterDropdown(cell, formatterParams, onRendered) {

  // If cell value has changed, assign callback
  if (cell.getOldValue() !== cell.getValue()) {
    onRendered(() => {
      const value = cell.getValue() || "";
      const element = cell.getElement();

      // Create elementDiv with some specific formatting...
      elementDiv = ...

      // Append to HTML element
      element.appendChild(elementDiv);
    });
  } else {
    // Reformat when cell value didn't change, to explicitly trigger a re-rendering
    // This works, as the table is shown correctly
    // HOWEVER, it also runs into an error within the browser, after execution of current function
    cell.getRow().reformat();
    
    // Then reassign cell variable with the updated cell, instead of the old cell
    cell = cell.getRow().getCell(cell.getColumn());

    // Continue code using new cell reference
    cell...
  }
}
```

It seems that the reference to the 'old cell' (before reformatting) is stored and used in the Tabulator source code. However, this cell doesn't have an HTML element assigned anymore (`cell.element = false`), and seems to be replaced by the reformatted cell. In my own code I could retrieve this reformatted cell, but within the source code, it seems to still have the reference to the old cell, ultimately running into an error.

[Image of error stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4vu7.png)

I have created a Fiddle that shows a minimal example of my solution. The `formatterDropdown` function has some comments to explain the issue. Current setup includes the reformatting, which gives a visually working table that does result into an error. Commenting the `cell.getRow().reformat()` command will give the initial issue, where the cell value is cleared and left empty on re-selection of the existing value.

The Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/3j69o510/2/

I'm using the latest Tabulator, version 5.5.